# Why hide exceptions on the web?

Tags: .net

Is there a real reason to hide exceptions on a webpage? I can understand hiding to not scare users but on the site i am developing theres no concern for scaring users. I imagine if you have SQL injection holes hiding the exception wont actually matter.

So what reasons might one have to hide exceptions on a webpage from users?

Answer (score 7):

> I imagine if you have SQL injection holes hiding the exception wont actually matter.

Oh, but it will. It can make the difference between the hole being found and exploited, and it *not* being found and exploited :)

Security through obscurity as the *only* security measure is dangerous. But it's a good thing to have as an *additional* one.

Exceptions and error messages

- Can give an attacker information about how the code is built (e.g. library functions used - catastrophic if one of them can be exploited)
- Can give an attacker information about the underlying system in general (OS / Platform, server, frameworks used, versions....)
- Can give an attacker information about the site's path structure and file locations. While not dangerous in itself, this is valuable information when exploiting a [directory traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal) security hole for example.

This is ample reason to hide this information from the public at all times.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Exceptions and error messages often contain extra information that an attacker might be able to exploit, such as:

- Table/Column names
- Connection strings
- Names/locations of files
- Method signatures and callstack info
- Operating system, service pack info  (valuable if you want to exploit an unpatched vulnerability)
- etc

Answer (score 1):

Error messages can leak information that attackers can use. Consider the recent vulnerability in ASP.NET—[MS10-070](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/Bulletin/MS10-070.mspx)—the different HTTP error codes provided information that could be used to determine the cryptographic keys in use. And once these were know the attacker could modify data that the ASP.NET runtime assumed were unchangeable and to access data that should be inaccessible.

If the HTTP status code is sufficient to provide an exploit, then consider the much richer information that an exception gives.